# Base64 String Image not properly showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display an image from a base64 string but it keeps showing up like this:

[image: img]

I've tried printing the img and I get something like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,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`

Am I wrong to try to just display it by doing `<img src={this.state.img} />`? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I've also updated this post to contain how I'm generating my base64 code. Essentially, I upload an image and crop that image using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop. Afterwards, I want to display the cropped image and that's where the trouble happens

```
<div>
     <input type="file" onChange={this.onSelectFile} />
</div>

onSelectFile = e => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener(
        "load",
        () =>
          this.setState({
            src: reader.result,
            openCropper: true
          }),
        false
      );
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };


function getCroppedImg(image, pixelCrop, fileName) {

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = pixelCrop.width;
  canvas.height = pixelCrop.height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    pixelCrop.x,
    pixelCrop.y,
    pixelCrop.width,
    pixelCrop.height,
    0,
    0,
    pixelCrop.width,
    pixelCrop.height
  );

  // As Base64 string
  const base64Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  return base64Image;
```

Comment: It doesn't look to be showing up properly just putting that as the `src`: https://jsfiddle.net/nhrwp2v4/

Comment: @CertainPerformance so is it probably an issue with the string?

Comment: @Tim yes, as this works as expected : https://jsfiddle.net/nhrwp2v4/1/

Comment: I know barely anything about base64 encodings or displaying them, but yeah, that would be my guess.

Comment: Getting `net::ERR_INVALID_URL` for that. Where did you get the base64 string from?

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll have to go back and see why it's generating the wrong base64 string

Comment: @Tim how are you getting the base64 string - can you post relevant code for that?

Comment: @DacreDenny I've updated my original post, thanks for looking into this :-)

Comment: @Tim thanks for that, does my answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems may be due to the context that your `onSelectFile` is called from. Currently, your defining `onSelectFile` as an arrow function. This in turn means that `this.setState` will be undefined when your `FileReader` loads the image data (and then attempts to update the state of the component).

Consider the following code that outlines a possible solution for your problem:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        src:''
    }
  }

  // Define as class method rather than arrow function
  onSelectFile(e) {

    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener(
        "load",
        () =>
          this.setState({
            src: reader.result,
            openCropper: true
          }),
        false
      );
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
     {/* invoke onSelectFile in this way to ensure calling context is 
         current component */}
     <input type="file" onChange={(e) => this.onSelectFile(e)} />
     <img src={this.state.src} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

For a working demo, [please see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mo9dzxq0/1/) - hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing an equals sign at the end of your base64 URL.

`data:image/jpeg;base64,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`

Comment: Oops that was a bad Copy + paste from me. Good catch though!